# Why is pointer dereference a prefix operator in C?

Tags: c

Why was the pointer dereference operator `*` designed to be a prefix operator while the other designator selectors, array element selector `[i]` and record field selector `.f`, use suffix operators. With only suffix selectors their individual precedence is not an issue.

Comment: You just wrinkled my brain.

Comment: If `*` is a suffix operator, then the compiler won't know what `x*=value`mean. Is it `x = x * value` or `(x*) = value`? But in prefix this it not ambiguous. `*x=value` will assign `value` to the memory pointed by `x` while `x*=value` will multiply `x` by `value` and store result in `x`.

Comment: How would the multiply operator be described otherwise?

Comment: Oh and try to rewrite `*x*=*x` if `*` is a suffix.

Comment: Good question. A suffix operator would have eliminated the need for `->`. Say it was `^`. Then, like at least one other language: `ptr^.field`

Comment: And ambiguity with `*` isn't the answer. First of all, _originally there was no_ `*=`, that operation existed but it was written `x =* y`.  A different character could have been used. Ambiguities are resolvable, etc...

Comment: This is one of these questions where the most natural answer is "Why not?"

Comment: For what it's worth, it **already has** an alias suffix form: `[0]`.

Comment: `[]` and `.` are binary operators .  `*` (dereference) is a unary operator. While the operand order is arbitrary in both cases, it's not valid to use one case to reason about the other.

Comment: The way it is now, all unary operators are prefix, except for postfix-increment (which only has to exist because prefix-increment is already taken). You could argue that is more consistent than having some prefix and some postfix. Would you want to see `5-` instead of `-5` , or `x!` for boolean negation?

Comment: @M.M I guess it's good that there's no built-in factorial operator. :)

Comment: The prefix `*` came from the B language, which was the inspiration for C.

Answer (score 3):

```
int *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
*c=3; //clear statement
c*=3; //would be ambiguous
```

I don't know why C implemented in this way but this is the first thing i think of.

Comment: `int *c = 3;` seems invalid

Comment: i added memory allocation

Comment: @AdityaGulavani It's technically valid, just probably not sensical

Comment: still that's based on using `*`. say we use `->` with no right hand side to mean "deference the whole thing" then it's totally usable.

Comment: @awksp; `int *c = 3; *c = 3` can blow up your system.

Comment: @awksp: It's not even technically valid. While *casts* from integer to pointer types are implementation-defined, there is no implicit conversion at all; it's a constraint violation. Compilers are just bad about enforcing this.

Comment: @R.. I didn't know that! ~~Surprised that clang didn't give anything more than a warning.~~ Bad at enforcing this, indeed. Something about saying how this is an error instead of warning about a conversion would be nice. Guess I have to change what I said to "it's valid in that it compiles, ..."

Comment: @awksp you could get in the habit of compiling in standard mode, e.g. `-std=c11 -pedantic`.  Compilers tend to default to a mode that is not going to throw new errors for codebases that compiled cleanly on older versions

Comment: @M.M I usually do, but it didn't occur to me that I should be doing that for quick tests.

Comment: Actually, when the prefix choice was made, `*=` did not exist, it was only `=*` in early C. So, it wasn't ambiguity, it was just existing practice *(copied it from B)*  retained by choice. It could have been a suffix, it just wasn't designed that way. Also, compilers aren't "bad" at enforcing the type system; they allow unsafe code in order to process type aliasing written before -- or in spite of -- the later stricter type rules as C evolved. Somewhere, there *could* be a firmware ROM where `int *c = 3` makes sense, but there probably isn't.

Comment: wow, thank you for detailed information @DigitalRoss

Answer (score 1):

It could have been a suffix. That was the case in Pascal and it worked out well there. In the end, dmr just made a choice and wrote it that way.

*Suffix Pros:*
     No need for `->`
     Left-to-right expression flow

*Suffix Cons:*
     *Maybe* more ambiguity, depending
     Declarations read a little less left-to-right

Comment: DMR didn't make this choice, he just copied it from B.

Comment: Thanks, good point.   Strictly speaking, of course, "copied from B" and "just made a choice" are not mutually exclusive statements.

Comment: Technically true. When he was designing C and based it on B, he chose to leave this part alone.